# Programm that can use Inputs from Telegramm to Control a website automatically

Tags: command-line, time-management, artificial-intelligence, remote-control, input-method

I am looking for an AI or non AI Tool with which I can read Out Telegramm Messages (from my PC, Telegramm App) smbdy. or better Said a friend of Mine sends me and which then gives Inputs to a specefic Website accordingly. Summed Up I want to use daily Inputs from Telegramm to creat certain Inputs of a Website I use. The Inputs in the Website are Always the Same for a specefic command from Telegramm.

A Note Here for Details. The Telegramm Messages are Kind of texti but Always the Same for the Same inputs on that given Website.

I am looking Forward for any Help, it would be highly appreciated

Thx, greetings

Jannik